# error with adding google analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

i have been trying to add google analytics to my app in development by following an online text tutorial which was ok at first but right at the end i get an error on this code... (specifically the code in the .m file)

Two things:

When i go on google analytics, i dont register any information and the line of code right below registers an error when i try to compile and run

Another thing is in all this code is there a section im supposed to put the tracker ID from google analytics?

P.S is it ok to include a link tot he tutorial i was following so that you guys know what im talking about? i dont wanna get banned so thought i would ask first...

```
 - (IBAction)tappedButtonOne:(id)sender {
     id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

 [tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"MyFirstScreen"
                     withAction:@"ButtonPress"
                     withLabel:@"ButtonOne"
                     withValue:nil];
}
```

here is the code i have in the .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : GAITrackedViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet ADBannerView *banner;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *txtinfo;
- (IBAction)tappedButtonOne:(id)sender;

@end
```

and here is the code i have in the .m

```
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc {
[_banner release];
[_txtinfo release];
[super dealloc];
}
- (IBAction)tappedButtonOne:(id)sender {
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

[tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"MyFirstScreen"
                    withAction:@"ButtonPress"
                     withLabel:@"ButtonOne"
                     withValue:nil];
 }
 @end
```

Comment: Can we have error which you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Another thing is in all this code is there a section im supposed to put the tracker ID from google analytics?

Yes, you need to initialize the tracker in your application delegate.

See the [Google Analytics SDK for iOS - Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) guide, especially Section 2 where it explains:

> To initialize the tracker, import the `GAI.h` header in your application delegate `.m` file and add this code to your application delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
  [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;

  // Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
  [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;

  // Optional: set Logger to VERBOSE for debug information.
  [[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];

  // Initialize tracker.
  id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXX-Y"];

}
```

It's here that you need to provide the tracker with your tracking ID by initializing the tracker with the `trackerWithTrackingId` method.

The rest of your code looks fine, and should work as expected when you've added the code above to your application delegate.

**Note:** It can take up to 24 hours for events to show up in Google Analytics after they have been sent by your app. If there's still nothing showing after 1 day, then you might need to check your code again.